# paid service that can send big amount of concurrent requests to my site for testing?

Tags: testing, web, server, performance-testing, devops

Is there a service that can load my website with big number of concurrent calls, service that can go to my site, authorize and do some things. Which one do you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no service which will do everything for you, you will have to choose a [load testing tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_testing#Load_testing_tools), script your scenario(s) and then choose the online service which supports the load testing tool of your choice.

Few examples:

- [LoadRunner](https://www.microfocus.com/en-us/products/loadrunner-professional/overview) and [StormRunner](https://www.microfocus.com/media/flyer/stormrunner_load_solution_flyer.pdf)
- [Gatling](https://gatling.io/) and [Gatling Frontline](https://gatling.io/gatling-frontline)
- [k6](https://k6.io/) and [LoadImpact](https://loadimpact.com/)
- [Apache JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/), [Locust](https://locust.io/), [Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/), [Gatling](https://gatling.io/), [Tsung](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/), https://www.selenium.dev/enter link description here, etc. and [BlazeMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/)